# Php-fpm displays "fail" on starting

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm

I run Ubuntu 13.04. I installed the nginx package and I compiled php-5.4.15 from source to run php-fpm. The problem is that when I do

```
 sudo service php-fpm start
```

I got

```
 Starting php-fpm ................................... fail
```

But php-fpm does start and I can display a phpinfo page on my local nginx server so I do not understand why I got this fail message.
Same thing, if after starting php-fpm, I do

```
 sudo service php-fpm restart
```

I got

```
Gracefully shutting down php-fpm warning, no pid file found - php-fpm is not running ?
Starting php-fpm [30-May-2013 07:54:23] ERROR: unable to bind listening socket 
for address '127.0.0.1:9000': Address already in use (98)
[30-May-2013 07:54:23] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
failed
```

Do you have any idea on where this problem could come from? Thank you!

Here is my ./configure instructions:

```
./configure \
    --enable-fpm \
    --enable-pdo \
    --with-pdo-mysql \
    --enable-sockets \
    --enable-exif \
    --enable-soap \
    --enable-ftp \
    --enable-wddx \
    --enable-pcntl \
    --enable-soap \
    --enable-bcmath \
    --enable-mbstring \
    --enable-dba \
    --enable-gd-native-ttf \
    --enable-zip \
    --enable-calendar \
    --with-mysql \
--with-mysql-sock \
    --with-mysqli \
    --with-pdo-sqlite \
    --with-iconv \
    --with-zlib \
    --with-bz2 \
    --with-gettext \
    --with-xmlrpc \
    --with-openssl \
--enable-shmop \
    --with-mhash \
    --with-mcrypt \
--with-kerberos \
--with-imap \
--with-imap-ssl \
--enable-sysvmsg \
--enable-sysvsem \
--enable-sysvshm \
    --with-xsl \
    --with-curl \
--enable-intl \
    --with-pcre-regex \
    --with-gd \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib \
    --with-png-dir=/usr/lib \
--with-libxml-dir=/usr/lib \
--with-t1lib=/usr \
    --with-ldap=/usr \
    --with-pear \
    --with-fpm-user=www-data \
    --with-fpm-group=www-data \
    --with-config-file-path=/etc/php-5.4.15/ \
    --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php-5.4.15/conf.d/ \
--with-libdir=lib
```

Php-fpm.conf:

```
  pid = /var/run/php-fpm.pid
  listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Nginx default:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #       # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #       # With php5-cgi alone:
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php5-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Completely kill it with `killall php-fpm` then start again. It looks like the init script just couldn't find a .pid file and is tossing false errors.

Comment: Thanks for you answser but it does not work. This problem appears event when I reboot my laptop (php does not start with the system, I didn't add it to system init script).

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -lpn | grep 9000`? It'll show what process is using the port, which you then can kill with `kill -9 pid`.

Comment: After starting my PC, `sudo netstat -lpn | grep 9000` outputs nothing. Then I do `sudo service php-fpm start`, and it displays  `Starting php-fpm ........fail` but actually starts because the output of netstat now shows `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4118/php-fpm.conf)`. But why does it say "fail" in the first place??

Comment: It's probably the init script messing up. You can review the startup log/init script to see, but if it's working then you can probably safely ignore it.

Comment: Well, it's just that I'm an idiot. My php-fpm.conf file had the directive `pid = /var/run/php-fpm.pid` and the default prefix is `/usr/local/var`. The init.d/php-fpm script had the directive `php_fpm_PID=${prefix}/var/run/php-fpm.pid` so I just edited my php-fpm.conf file like this `pid = run/php-fpm.pid` and now everything works perfect! Thanks for your help!